# `table "django_migrations" already exists` error with Python 3 and SQLite3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.6

I've recently started receiving an error that I'm having trouble identifying with a Django project using SQLite. The project linked below was/is previously Python 2/3 compatible, though I primarily ran it using Python 2. Recently, I switched over most of my computers and projects to default to using Python 3 (I know, better late than never, right?). Additionally, I upgraded the project from Django 1.7 to 1.11. After this, the project started receiving the `table already exists` error, but *only* when running the `migrate` command using `python3`.

I also *only* get the error when running `python3 manage.py migrate`. For instance, `python3 manage.py test` works just fine, which is a bit baffling given test first runs the migrations. Running `python2 manage.py migrate` works just fine, no errors.

I am running Python 3.6.4, installed via Homebrew on a Mac, and the error I received is:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in ensure_schema
   raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (table "django_migrations" already exists)
```

I run into this exact same issue—broken with Python 3 but working with Python 2—on multiple computers, so I'd imagine anyone else will see the same issue. You should be able to reproduce the issue with the following steps:

1. `git clone git@github.com:alexdlaird/django-bootstrap-authentication-template-project.git && cd django-bootstrap-authentication-template-project`
2. `make install`
3. `python2 manage.py migrate` - note that it works just fine
4. `rm db.sqlite` for a fresh start
5. `python3 manage.py migrate` - note that it fails with the error shown above
   5x. `rm db.sqlite` for a fresh start
   5x. `python3 manage.py test` - note that it works just fine

To see the migrations run against a MySQL instance (the project assumes you have a default Homebrew MySQL instance running locally, but this can be configured in `.env` if not), run `python3 manage.py migrate` and observe that this works just fine with Python 2 or 3, so the issue appears isolated to SQLite migrations.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here?

-- **.pyc Update** --

I have executed `find . -name \*.pyc -delete` between running the above commands, but this does nothing to alleviate the situation. This makes sense, given the issue persists on a fresh clone, but I think we can eliminate it being an issue with Python's cached files.

Comment: Given the lack of traction here, and some additional debugging I've done that makes me pretty confident it's a bug related to Python 3.x and Django 1.10 and higher, I've submitted a question the Django users mailing list below. I will update this question as I get a response there.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/iUGQpqPEltg

Comment: I have done a bit of debugging with this issue, going back and forth between 2.7 and 3.6. What I'm seeing seems to be that the issue is related to table names—probably unicode related. For example, watching the returned `get_tables_list` in value of in `python3.6/django/db/backends/sqlite3/introspection.py` shows an empty list (I believe because of the b'' preceding the string, which is hijacking what otherwise should be an array index), whereas in the same file and function in 2.7 all the existing tables are properly return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it. For others that may run into a similar issue, here is the offending lines in my project that I simply had to remove: https://github.com/alexdlaird/django-bootstrap-authentication-template-project/commit/db16ff88d0d6c25eed38e52bd8332c721ed21e2f?diff=split#diff-e398a065684e871bec35f76ea80f20a7

This was an artifact of an ages old hack used for Python 2.5/6 and SQLite (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744632/change-text-factory-in-django-sqlite))—it's by no means a good solution, but given SQLite was only used for dev and testing, it worked just fine. It was certainly better than banging my head against Python 2/SQLite unicode incompatibilities for hours on end.

Not surprisingly, I forgot about this hack long ago, and it didn't occur to me until I was debugging the Django code (describe in [the comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49503235/table-django-migrations-already-exists-error-with-python-3-and-sqlite3/49505445?noredirect=1#comment86289026_49503235)) and realized why the string tables names had ugly byte wrappers.

Answer (score -1):

Clear your django migration cache before each try.

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

Comment: No dice. I've tried this many times from clean clones as well, so that's not surprising. Good thought though!

Comment: JFI ,if you run python3 manage.py migrate <app_name> does it work?

Comment: Nope. I've tried that both with my apps as well as cleaning up and trying to prerun Django's app migrations first (for instance, sessions, or their "auth" migration). All migrations receive the same error.